# Create a file of a specific dimension filled with zeroes

Tags: c, string, merge

I'm trying to create a method which, given multiple strings, merges them together. Now, this is what I came up with. The main is purely for test so in the end I'll have only one part string at the time, the location on which that part belongs in the full string, and the final string where I need to put these parts.

```
int mergeParts(char* text, char* part, int position){
    int printSpot = position * CONTENTSIZE;

    strcat(text[printSpot], part);
    printf("%s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem with this code is a segmentation error, I tried multiple things but the only one that seems to work is using `strcat(text, part);` without using the "location" on which the part of the string must be copy.

```
#define CONTENTSIZE 10
int main(){
    int i;
    char* part1 = "This is a ";
    char* part2 = "test with ";
    char* part3 = "something ";
    char* part4 = "that i wro";
    char* part5 = "te in it";

    int totParts = 5;
    char* parts[totParts] = {part1,part2,part3,part4,part5};
    int stringSize = totParts * CONTENTSIZE;
    char* finalString = malloc(stringSize);

    for(i = 0; i<totParts; i++){
        mergeParts(finalString, parts[i], i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this specifying to the string the location where to copy the parts.

A good example that I can give you to explain better what I'm looking for is:

I have a empty string `"------------------------------"`

I have to write inside `"This "; "is an"; " exam"; "ple o"; "f the"; " text";`

If I receive `" exam";`, the result in my string has to be `"---------- exam---------------"`.
Then I receive " text"; and so the result will be `"---------- exam---------- text"`

And so on until I have `"This is an example of the text";`

Comment: In order to avoid the necessity of wrapping `mergeParts()` in a `for` loop, you might consider converting it into a [variadic function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm). This would be a perfect scenario for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `strcat(text[printSpot], part);` is the point. I think you should use `strcat(&(text[printSpot]), part);` instead. `text[printSpot]` will have the actual char data like `'e'`, not the address of the string which is required for `strcat`.

Or you can use `strcat(text+printSpot,part)` simply.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue causing the segfault is that you're not passing the correct argument to `strcat`:

```
strcat(text[printSpot], part);
```

Both arguments are expected to be of type `char *`, but for the first argument you're passing in a single `char`.  Passing a non-pointer where a pointer is expected invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, the character being passed in is being interpreted as an address (which is invalid), and that invalid address is dereferenced, causing a crash.

You should be passing in the address of that array element:

```
strcat(&text[printSpot], part);
```

You also haven't initialized the bytes in `finalString`.  The `strcat` function expects its first argument to point to a null terminated string, but because none of the allocated bytes have been initialized, you potentially  read past the end of allocated memory, which again invokes undefined behavior.

Putting an empty string in `finalString` will take care of this:

```
strcpy(finalString, "");
```

Or equivalently:

```
finalString[0] = '\x0';
```

This allows the test program to work properly, where you're appending to an empty string in order, but it doesn't satisfy the requirement of updating parts of an existing string, possibly in the middle.  Using `strcat` will null-terminate the destination string after the second argument is appended, resulting in anything that might have come after it to be lost.

Assuming `finalString` is initially set with an "empty" string as in your example of the proper length, you should instead use `memcpy`.  This will copy over only the characters in the string and not add a null terminating byte:

```
memcpy(&text[printSpot], part, strlen(part));
```

You'll also want to populate `finalString` with `'-'` characters to start:

```
char* finalString = malloc(stringSize + 1);
memset(finalString, '-', stringSize);
finalString[stringSize]=0;
```

Output:

```
This is a ----------------------------------------
This is a test with ------------------------------
This is a test with something --------------------
This is a test with something that i wro----------
This is a test with something that i wrote in it--
```

Comment: "You should be passing in the address of that array element:" I think you might have a typo (missing `&`) in the next line after that.

Comment: @SiggiSv Good catch. Fixed.